# how can i take out the version in my main.css file?

Tags: wordpress-version

I have the same problem as you, i am seing my old css file, after editing it, because at the end of the css call appears something like this: "css/main.css?ver=4.2.2. If i take out the part that says "?ver=4.2.2" i could see my real main.css file.
Please help, I need someone.

Comment: That 4.2.2 part is the WordPress version parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove query strings from scripts and style sheets with a function in the theme's functions.php file.

```
// Remove Query Strings from enqueue scripts
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'remove_query_string' ); // CSS files
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'remove_query_string' ); // javascripts
function remove_query_string( $url )
{
    return remove_query_arg( 'ver', $url );
}
```

Be sure you have made a child theme so you don't lose changes upon a theme update. See [Child Themes « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)